# Android viewpager overlap ImageView from next and previous with the current page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-adapter

What I am trying to do is, using the viewpager, create a photo album that when the user slides to next/previous, the opacity(Alpha) of the current image decreases and the opacity of the next/previous increases based on the sliding progress. The point is to give the impression that all the images are stacked and that they just fade from beneath the current picture. However, the title of the image, shows from left or right as a normal viewpager would do. Any ideas ? 
My page fragment layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/slider_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     /> <!-- #FFF #000 -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slider_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
        android:text="All-in-one"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slider_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="image desc"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a PageTransformer similar to the examples here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#depth-page

The extra step you need to do, is when you get the View in the `pageTransform()` method you need to get the Views you want to animate - ImageView in your case (using `view.findViewById(R.id.slider_image)`) and change the alpha value.